# probably a simple PHP editing?

Tags: forms, input, auto

Script AUTO POPULATES the URL input field with http:// .. and unfortunately can't be overwritten by editing the URL in the Admin section of this directory script.
So i end up with stuff like http://https://.
I would therefor like to stop the script from auto populating anything into the URL input field (so people can just copy and paste their full URL, no matter if https or http.

Here are the 2 lines that seem to be doing the auto population (or maybe it's just one of the two, i am not a coder)

```
      if (strcmp("http://", substr($url, 0, 7)) !== 0) {
      $url = "http://" . $url;
  }
```

and in a later section

```
         if (strpos($nueva,"http://")=== FALSE) {
        $nueva = "http://" . $urlc . $nueva;
     }
```

Do i just remove the http:// as in

```
if (strcmp("", substr($url, 0, 7)) !== 0) {
      $url = "" . $url;
```

and that would stop it, or is it a bit more complicated or just a different trick i need to change??

Comment: I don't know PHP too well but from what I can tell, the code at the bottom doesn't really do anything... it prepends the URL with an empty string if the code gets inside the `if` block.

Comment: Okay, so i still have the same problem, how can i edit the string to stop the auto population of http://??